# Spawn an independent and timed process in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am manipulating large amount of data and need to pre-calculate some reports data independently from the calculation process.

The data is already handled through a pool of subprocesses and I cannot slow any one them down by locking it with data reporting at the end of each processing cycle.

So, in short, **I need to spawn an independent process (from a subprocess...) that would shut *itself* down after a given time** and no, *I do not want a CRON process* as synching it with my calculation would be hellish.

Any idea so I don't end up with tons of runaway threads clogging my system?

Comment: Why would you need to lock it with data reporting? Why not spawn off processes that do data reporting at the end of the calculation process? This question might be a little too broad for SO the way it's currently written.

Comment: Can you use a work queue to a reporting thread that updates the reports? I'd assume that on each cycle completed you post a packet of data that is needed to create the report on the work queue.

Comment: By data reporting you mean things like writing to file? Then you do *not* need a subprocess. You can just use threads since it's IO bound. You could simply spawn a thread and let it collect the results of a `Queue` that the subprocesses fill with the results.